# What languages are Amazon's AWS Management Console written?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What language is Amazon's AWS Management Console written?

[image]

Comment: Judging from what I know about the AWS tech base after talking with Amazon, I'd assume the backend and most of the page generation uses Java and some framework (one of the file browsers they use requires Java authorization, too). And of course the front end uses generated HTML and JS and CSS. You could reproduce it in any language, though.

Comment: Thanks sir, yeah I was really impressed with the UI.  The simplicity makes it really easy to use.  My guess was java and html/js/css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most web applications, the Amazon AWS Management Console is written in the client-side languages Javascript, CSS, and HTML. On the server side, they seem to use [`pack:tag`](http://www.galan.de/pages/packtag) (just look at the `X-Powered-By` response header), which is a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)-compatible library, so I assume they use Java there.

Comment: Where have you seen the usage of pack:tag, I can't find it, on which page?

Comment: I saw it on [the main EC2 console page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home), but I don't see it there anymore. My guess remains that they use some Java framework, though.

Comment: AWS is build upon Xen which has a tool stack written in OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

Java on the backend (via AWS Flow). The frontend was built using Javascript/CSS using the YUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit.
It is likely that Amazon developed their own framework/widgets based on it.

Look at some of the these ids and classes: 
gwt-Image ON
gwt-debug-leftNav-Home 
__gwt_historyFrame (This one is a classic give away!)